# Find Connected Components

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X = \mathbb{R^2}$ and let $F_k$ be the closed line segment joining $(-1,2^{-k})$ and $(1,2^{-k})$

Additionally let $a = (-1,0) \ ,\ b=(1,0)$

Consider $A = \{a,b\} \cup \  (\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k)\ $

Show that the Components of A are $\{a\},\{b\}$ and $F_k\ \  \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

I usually use the definition of Component to be non empty subset which is simultaneously open closed and connected.

Now it seems geometrically clear that each $F_k$ is both Open and Closed in $A$ since you can always find an open/closed set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ to intersect $A$ and get back only $F_k$

I'm stuck with showing $F_k$ is Connected. I think this has something to do with Path Connectedness but I haven't done much of that topic yet.

On the other hand I know that $\{a\},\{b\}$ are Connected in $A$ but I cant show they are open/closed.

Comment: The singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are closed but not open. Components are in general not open. (And each $F_k$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, so any proof of connectedness for that interval carries over.)

Comment: Your definition of component is incorrect: the components are defined to be the maximal connected subsets. So once you've proved that $F_k$ is connected (yes, it has to do with path connectedness), then you have to prove the maximality statement: for any subset $Y \subset X$ that contains $F_k$ as a proper subset, $Y$ is disconnected.

Comment: I see. I think I messed up reading the definition in my book. It says there a non empty subset which is Open, Closed, Connected is a Component. But I gues the converse does not hold.

Comment: @Exc Right. Closed, open, and connected means it's a component. That applies to the $F_k$. But not all components are open (they are in locally connected spaces, however).